# How to setup the account manager type to sign transactions in Go?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, accounts, golang

**TL;DR:**
I've setup a private Ethereum node, and I want to send a signed transaction to it. By reading the docs I know that there's an account `Manager` type which can access a `Wallet` type which has a `SignTx` method that I want to use for this purpose. I'm having an issue setting up the account `Manager` type to begin this process.

**The Problem:**

The `NewManager` function requires a type which implements the `Backend` interface. The problem here is that I can't find any docs describing (accurately) how to initialize an account `Manager` with a `Backend`. The only backend available in the account source is `SimulatedBackend` meant for testing (source: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/3fa0fa713bc1508835bdecd7dea78ff09803e327/accounts/abi/bind/backends).

**What I've tried:**

The docs (here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Native:-Account-management#keystores-from-go) say that one can be initialized this way:

`am := accounts.NewManager("/path/to/keystore", accounts.StandardScryptN, accounts.StandardScryptP);`

However, it does not compile as the `accounts.StandardScryptN` and `accounts.StandardScryptP` do not exist, and when replaced with their integer equivilents (`2` and `1` respectively), the compile error states that the keystore path argument (`"/path/to/keystore"`) does not implement the `Backend` interface, which makes sense. My guess is that the docs are not updated, and because of that the `NewManager` function cannot compile with these arguments.

Docs for the `NewManager` type for reference: https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts#NewManager

**Question:**

Does anyone know how to initialize the account manager correctly to begin signing transactions in Go?

Comment: Figured this out earlier, will update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that a `Manager` is not needed to interact with accounts and sign transactions, rather, we can create a keystore, and find accounts and  wallets using it's [doc methods](https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/keystore#KeyStore). We can create a keystore like so:

```
ks := keystore.NewKeyStore(
    KEYSTORE_DIR,
    keystore.LightScryptN,
    keystore.LightScryptP)
```

where `keystore` is the import `"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/keystore"`, and `KEYSTORE_DIR` is the `keystore` directory for account private key files.