# Create Ethereum Account using golang

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, accounts, golang

I want to create ethereum account using golang. I am following [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Native:-Account-management) guide but I am stuck with errors just at the beginning of code.

```
accountManager:=accounts.NewManager(".ethereum/rinkeby/keystore",accounts.StandardScryptN, accounts.StandardScryptP))
```

Error : Unresolved Reference "accounts.StandardScryptN" & "accounts.StandardScryptP"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the guide is out of date.

[`StandardScryptN`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/bedf6f40aff0dd14bfab533a37c329ddc9a4bdd5/accounts/keystore/keystore_passphrase.go#L57) and `StandardScryptP` are now in the [`keystore`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/bedf6f40aff0dd14bfab533a37c329ddc9a4bdd5/accounts/keystore/keystore_passphrase.go#L26) package, not the `accounts` package. You'll need to update your `import` accordingly.

Comment: sir, you are right. I replaced the params but still accounts.NewManager() is not accepting those params

Comment: Is the error the same? How are you importing the `keystore` package? Are you still importing the `accounts` package? Can you update your question with an [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of the code that's failing?

Comment: Actually, accounts.NewManager() accept an Interface called "Backend" which is part of  "accounts" package. Sir, the problem is I don't know how to use it

Comment: Sir, there are only two imports(accounts, keystore) and only one line of code which I have mentioned in my question

Comment: Okay, unsure what the issue is (without having a play around with it). If you don't explicitly need the Manager functionality, another option would just be to create a standalone keystore, as per the answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/13604/52).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `go-ethereum` libraries to generate an account

```
import "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
import "encoding/hex"

// Create an account
key, err := crypto.GenerateKey()

// Get the address
address := crypto.PubkeyToAddress(key.PublicKey).Hex()
// 0x8ee3333cDE801ceE9471ADf23370c48b011f82a6

// Get the private key
privateKey := hex.EncodeToString(key.D.Bytes())
// 05b14254a1d0c77a49eae3bdf080f926a2df17d8e2ebdf7af941ea001481e57f
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I want to create password protected account

Answer (score 0):

If you have a private key hex string, you can recover the account by this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
)

func main() {
    // not started with 0x
    priKey := "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"
    ecdsa, err := crypto.HexToECDSA(priKey)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    address := crypto.PubkeyToAddress(ecdsa.PublicKey).Hex()
    fmt.Println(address) //0x7E5F4552091A69125d5DfCb7b8C2659029395Bdf
}
```